# TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable can not save a file

Tags: python, file, typeerror

I'm new to Python and am testing myself a bit but i cant solve this problem, can anyone help me?
my code is below

I am offering improvements and tips for my code

i have this error code:

```
`File "c:\Users\lauro\Desktop\camo_grind\main.py", line 44, in <module>with open("done.txt","w") as done:TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
# COD mastery camo liste
user = str(input("neu, fertig, liste zeigen oder fertige liste"))

open1 = ["mp5", "lmg",]
done1 = []
#Neue waffen werden hinzugefügt 
if user == "neu":
     number1 = int(input("wie viel neue ?"))
     while number1 >0:
          open1.append(input("welche sind neu"))
          number1 -= 1

#fertige waffe werden gelöscht von der Liste
if user == "fertig":
     number2 = int(input("wie viel fertig"))
     while number2 >0:
          done = str(input("welche waffe ist fertig"))
          open1.remove(done)
          done1.append(done)    
          number2 -= 1

#druckt liste aus bei Befehl von der eingabe
if user == "liste":
     print(open1)

#druckt fertige lsite bei befehl von eingabe 
elif user == "fertige liste":
     if done1.count(done) == 0:
          print("noch keine gemacht!!!!")
     else:
          print(done1)
     
with open ("open.txt","w") as open:
     open.write(", ".join(open1))

with open("done.txt","w") as done:
     open.write(", ".join(done1))

#nur kontrolle
print(open1)
print(done1)
```